# How to block wordpress admin by htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I was trying to block the access from public to my /wp-admin. I can achieve it by doing the following htaccess but the problem is I need to add an exception for sub-url which is /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

Comment: If my answer solved the problem can you please mark it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file and upload it to your `/sitefolder/wp-admin/` folder. Then add this:

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
AuthName "WordPress Admin Access Control" AuthType Basic 
<LIMIT GET> 
order deny,allow 
deny from all 
# whitelist Syed's IP address 
allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx 
# whitelist David's IP address 
allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx 
# whitelist Amanda's IP address 
allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx
# whitelist Muhammad's IP address 
allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx 
# whitelist Work IP address 
allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx
</LIMIT>
```

Replace the xxx with the IP addresses you want to allow to execute admin php files.
Credit to
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/protect-your-admin-folder-in-wordpress-by-limiting-access-in-htaccess/ for the rules.